# Sed to remove substring | Can I make a flexible pattern to remove numbers before tab?

Tags: bash, sed

I wanted to ask some advice on an issue that I'm having in removing a substring from a string. I have a file with many lines like the following:

```
    DOG; CSQ| 0.1234 | abcd | \t CAT
```

where `\t` represents a literal tab.

My aim is to remove a substring by using `sed 's/CSQ.*|//g'` so that I can get the following output:

```
    DOG; CAT
```

However I face a problem where all the rows aren't formatted the same. For example, I also get lines such as:

```
    DOG; CSQ| 0.1234 | abcd | 0 \t CAT
    DOG; CSQ| 0.1234 | abcd | 0.9187 \t CAT
```

My code fails at this point because instead of getting `DOG; CAT` for all lines, I get:

```
    DOG; CAT    
    DOG; 0 CAT
    DOG; 0.9187 CAT
```

I've searched for possible solutions but I'm having difficulty (I'm also quite new to bash). I imagine there's something that I can do with `sed` that will handles all cases but I'm not sure.

Comment: The `\t` symbolises a tab character or "\" followed by "t" two characters?

Comment: Try `sed 's/CSQ.*|[^\t]*\t//' file`, see [online demo](https://ideone.com/Ql4Szs). Or even `'s/CSQ|[^\t]*\t//'`

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew, this worked perfectly. I admit that shortly after posting this, it clicked that I could use the "\t in some way" although when I tried it I was stilling having issues. I think writing it out like this helped. Thanks for the help, I'll have to start learning my regex.

Comment: @Jepson I [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68269807/3832970) a bit simpler solution.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `awk '{print $1,$NF}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find and replace all text from `CSQ` till the last `|` and all chars after that till the tab including it using

```sh
sed 's/CSQ.*|.*\t//' file > newfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/FShWMk).

The `CSQ.*|.*\t` is a POSIX BRE pattern that matches

- `CSQ` - a `CSQ` string
- `.*` - any text
- `|` - a pipe char
- `.*` - any text
- `\t` - TAB char.

If the `\t` are two-char combinations double the backslash before `t`:

```sh
sed 's/CSQ.*|.*\\t//' file > newfile
```

See [this online demo](https://ideone.com/DlJosV).

Comment: Hi @Wiktor, thanks again for this. I've hit another snag in my downstream analysis and I wondered if there's a way to retain the tab (`\t`) before `CAT`? I've tried reintroducing the tab by using `sed  '/CAT/i  \t'` but this does not seem to work.

Comment: @Jepson Yes, use a capturing group in the regex and `\1` backreference in the replacement part: `sed 's/CSQ.*|.*\(\t\)/\1/' file > newfile`

Comment: Thanks again @Wiktor, that works perfectly. I appreciate the clear explanations too.

Answer (score 0):

So optionally match it.

```
sed 's/CSQ.*|\( [0-9.]*\)\?//g'
```

You can learn regex online with fun with regex crosswords.

Answer (score 0):

`awk` makes this pretty easy.

```
$: awk '/CSQ.*\t/{print $1" "$NF}' file
DOG; CAT
DOG; CAT
DOG; CAT
```

Note that the file has to have actual tabs, not `\t` sequences. `awk` will read the `\t` correctly.

If there are no other formatted lines in the file that you want, then maybe just

```
$: awk '{print $1" "$NF}' file
DOG; CAT
DOG; CAT
DOG; CAT
```